# Is there a warning for `async void`?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, async-await, .net-7.0

I'd like to completely eliminate the possibility that my project contains `async void`. If somebody attempts to write an `async void` method, there should be a build error or warning.

The compiler doesn't seem to complain on its own, and my attempts to find an analyzer that could do it have failed.

Is this possible?

---

Motivation:

- We have an ASP.NET Core API project, where throwing an exception from a an `async void` controller method crashes the entire process (we can handle exceptions from `async Task` methods just fine).
- Also, we have some async tests in an MSTest project, where forgetting to return `Task` could lead to some strange wonkiness during the test run.

We don't have any event handlers and don't need `async void` anywhere, so it's safest to simply forbid it.

Comment: This appears to do what you want:  https://roslyn-analyzers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/analyzers-info/async/avoid-async-void-methods.html